# App Engine development environment fails to launch app

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After upgrading my app engine dev environment to 1.7.6, an app cannot start. When running locally, I get the following error, which is not inside the project code.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py",
>   line 194, in 
>       _run_file(**file**, globals())   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py",
>   line 190, in _run_file
>       execfile(script_path, globals_)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime.py",
>   line 101, in 
>       main()   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime.py",
>   line 78, in main
>       sandbox.enable_sandbox(config)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py",
>   line 164, in enable_sandbox
>       from google.appengine.runtime import runtime   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/runtime.py",
>   line 39, in 
>       from google.appengine.runtime import cgi   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/cgi.py",
>   line 31, in 
>       from email import feedparser ImportError: cannot import name feedparser

Strangely, four other apps will start without error. I cannot find anything in this failed project that has changed or would lead to this error.

Also of note...

- The app runs when deployed to App Engine
- When I downgrade the SDK to 1.7.5, the app starts running again

App definition

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

derived_file_type:
- python_precompiled

inbound_services:

handlers:

- url: /css
  static_dir: public/css

- url: /img
  static_dir: public/img

- url: /js
  static_dir: public/js

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: public/img/favicon.ico
  upload: public/img/favicon.ico

- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: email.email.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

Comment: Can you post some code? What is in your app.yaml?

Comment: Do you run it on a Mac? Did you install PyObj?

Comment: I added my app definition above but note that when I downgrade back to 1.7.5 of the SDK it starts working again. It also works when deployed to App Engine