# dev_appserver.py is giving me an error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After upgrading GAE to 1.7.6 on OS X Lion, I'm getting an error I can't resolve when I run dev_appserver.py. It was working fine in the previous version. Initially the error said I needed to install PyObjC and PIL, which I did, using pip. Now, it says `can't open file '/usr/local/bin/_python_runtime.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Here is the full error:

```
INFO     2013-04-01 23:01:15,091 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-04-01 23:01:15,660 sdk_update_checker.py:272] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2013-04-01 23:01:15,705 api_server.py:152] Starting API server at: http://localhost:50096
INFO     2013-04-01 23:01:15,721 dispatcher.py:98] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-04-01 23:01:15,759 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/usr/local/bin/_python_runtime.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
ERROR    2013-04-01 23:01:15,785 http_runtime.py:221] unexpected port response from runtime ['']; exiting the development server
INFO     2013-04-01 23:01:16,775 api_server.py:517] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2013-04-01 23:01:16,775 api_server.py:520] Saving search indexes
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown)
```

I found a similar post about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696835/app-engine-development-environment-fails-to-launch-app), but it was on a Windows 7 machine and it doesn't appear he's found a solution (or perhaps he did and didn't follow up). Any ideas?

Edit: It works with the GoogleAppEngineLauncher GUI but not the command line. Not sure why.

Comment: Whats your default python when you run from the command line ?

Comment: Do you mean the python path? `which python` gives `usr/local/bin/python`.​ I have one virtualenv set up, but I'm running this on my system installation.

Comment: You said it worked fine from the launcher but not from the command line, which could indicate you are trying to run the dev server from the command line (whatever you get if you just type python) that is invalid for the new dev server.  For instance I found in the past that I couldn't run the dev server from a virtualenv linked python.  Maybe the version of python isn't supported (I get the port error if I try to run the dev server with pypy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my response to Fat Lotus, here's what worked for me:

I updated GAE Launcher again which recreated the symlinks and now it works fine. The current symlink that `/usr/local/bin/_python_runtime.py` links to is `/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-de‌​fault.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py`

Answer (score 2):

I've been having this problem as well (related to a Homebrew install); I've managed to get things working by using the following:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/google-app-engine/1.7.5/share/google-app-engine/_python_runtime.py /usr/local/bin/_python_runtime.py
```

Comment: Sorry for the very late response... Your suggestion actually didn't work, but I updated GAE Launcher again which recreated the symlinks and now it works fine. The current symlink that `/usr/local/bin/_python_runtime.py` links to is `/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py`

Comment: Oh, sorry -- yes, that will only work for people who have used Homebrew to install the launcher. Perhaps create a new answer and then mark that as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error in regards to _python_runtime.py not being found.  It was caused by not running the GoogleAppEngineLauncher by first copying the application to the local drive.

Make sure you read the error messages carefully, as I didn't read all of them at first.  Running the installer from the local disk resolved this issue, at least for me.